# Apache pdfbox claims that PDF documents are encrypted (but they are not!) - fix?

Tags: java, pdfbox

In my program I am downloading misc. PDF documents and at the very end I want to merge those into one combined document using Apache pdfbox (v1.8.8).
For some strange reason the PDFMergerUtility fails claiming that the files are encryped - which they are obviously not! I can open them in Adobe Reader and other PDF viewers without any issue and without having to provide any password.

The Java exception and stack trace reads:

```
Feb 28, 2015 6:25:54 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser parse
INFO: Document is encrypted
Failed to merge all files into downloaded\page merged.pdf: Error: source PDF is encrypted, can't append encrypted PDF documents.
java.io.IOException: Error: source PDF is encrypted, can't append encrypted PDF documents.
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDFMergerUtility.java:284)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:241)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:194)
    at mmo.pull_ct.PullCT.mergePDFs(PullCT.java:481)
```

Anybody having the same issue and/or maybe knows a fix or work-around?
This is using Java (1.)8 under Windows 8.1 (x64).

Comment: Some documents have an empty user password, but a non-empty owner password. You can open such a file, but there will be restrictions, e.g. no printing or no text extraction. To be sure, open the PDF file with NOTEPAD++, and search for "/Encrypt". If you find it, then the file is encrypted.

Comment: *I can open them in Adobe Reader and other PDF viewers without any issue and without having to provide any password.* - That does not prove anything. PDF standards define a standard password which is appended to the given password. By this means empty passwords given by the viewing user are allowed.

Comment: Right - the file *was* indeed encrypted but with an empty password. Hadn't known that this is the usual way to enforce PDF restrictions and that misc. viewers try that automatically when encountering an "encrypted" file! Thanks both!

Comment: @mmo You can answer your question. I would have +1'ed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Answered by the comments from Tilman Hausherr and mkl above.
The Files *were* encrypted but using an empty password. Trying that got me going.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As the pdf have empty password. This worked for me in a test project. Adding this answer as it took some time for me to figure it out, may help someone looking for the same issue.

```
PDDocument dl = PDDocument.load(is);
if (dl.isEncrypted()) {
    // then try to load using
    dl.decrypt("");
    dl.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
    // save a copy of the file
    dl.save(tempPath);
 }
```